# Set Windows Firewall to Stateless?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008, tcp, windows-firewall, udp

Is there a way to "dumb down" the Windows Firewall on Win2003 or Win2008 from stateful to "stateless", and have it only do basic port filtering on the public interface?

If not, is there a simple, stateless software firewall I can replace Windows Firewall with?

I'm looking to do this for performance reasons.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just looking for simple packet-filtering then RRAS with some rules added in should be able to do what you want.

Comment: Any pointers on how to get started? I read about the RRAS static filters and they seem to be the thing I'm looking for, but I thought they only applied to actual RRAS servers, and that seems a bit heavy.

Comment: Actually, just follow the wizards. Got it to work in a couple of minutes. Thanks!

Comment: Well just to be clear for everyone... you install RRAS, then go into its MMC snap-in, and you expand "IP routing" then select the "General" item underneath - NOT "NAT/Basic Firewall".

With "IP routing" selected, right-click your external network interface in the list on the right, select Properties, then click "Inbound Filters".